# Efficiently merge GeoDataFrames if Polygon from one contains Point from second

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

i have two GeoDataFrames
gdf_point:

```
       Unnamed: 0   latitude  longitude                  geometry
0               0  50.410203   7.236583  POINT (7.23658 50.41020)
1               1  51.303545   7.263082  POINT (7.26308 51.30354)
2               2  50.114965   8.672785  POINT (8.67278 50.11496)
```

and gdf_poly:

```
       Unnamed: 0  Id                                       geometry
0               0  301286  POLYGON ((9.67079 49.86762, 9.67079 49.86987, ...
1               1  302258  POLYGON ((9.67137 54.75650, 9.67137 54.75874, ...
2               2  302548  POLYGON ((9.66808 48.21535, 9.66808 48.21760, ...
```

I want to match if a point from gdf_point is contained by any of the polygons of gdf_poly, if yes i want the Id of that polygon to be added to the corresponding row of gdf_point.

Here is my current code:

```
COUNTER = 0

def f(x, gdf_poly, df_new_point):
    global COUNTER

    for row in gdf_poly.itertuples():
        geom = getattr(row, 'geometry')
        id = getattr(row, 'Id')
        if geom.contains(x):
            print('True')
            df_new_point.loc[COUNTER, 'Id'] = id

    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1

df_new_point = gdf_point
gdf_point['geometry'].apply(lambda x: f(x, gdf_poly, df_new_point))
```

This works and does what i want it to do. But the Problem is its way to slow, it takes about 50min to do 10k rows (multithreading is a future option), and i want it to be able to handle multiple million rows. There must be a better and faster way to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two dataframes on their geometries (not on column or index values), use one of geopandas's [spatial joins](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins). They have a whole section of the docs about it - it's great - give it a read!

There are two workhorse spatial join functions in geopandas:

- **[`GeoDataFrame.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin.html)** joins two dataframes based on a binary predicate performed on all combinations of geometries, one of `intersects`, `contains`, `within`, `touches`, `crosses`, or `overlaps`. You can specify whether you want a `left`, `right`, or `inner` join based on the `how` keyword argument
- **[`GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html)** joins two dataframes based on which geometry in one dataframe is closest to each element in the other. Similarly, the `how` argument gives `left`, `right`, and `inner` options. Additionally, there are two arguments to `sjoin_nearest` not available on `sjoin`:

  - `max_distance`: The max_distance argument specifies a maximum search radius for matching geometries. This can have a considerable performance impact in some cases. If you can, it is highly recommended that you use this parameter.
  - `distance_col`: If set, the resultant GeoDataFrame will include a column with this name containing the computed distances between an input geometry and the nearest geometry.

You can optionally use these global `geopandas.sjoin` and `geopandas.sjoin_nearest` functions, or use the methods [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin.html) and [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html). Note, however, that the docs include a warning that the root-level functions may be deprecated at some point in the future, and recommend the use of the GeoDataFrame methods.

So in your case:

```py
merged = gdf_poly.sjoin(gdf_point, predicate="contains")
```

will do the trick, though if you want to match polygons where the point falls exactly on the boundary, you may want to consider `predicate="intersects"`.

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly. Thank you so much :).