# Make a condition if a polygon contains a point

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, shapely

I need to set up a **condition** using **shapely** that accuses whether or not a point belongs to a polygon.

If the value is true, a message "point belongs to polygon" should be displayed. If the point does not belong, then the message "the point does not belong to the polygon" should be displayed.

Also, if the point belongs to the polygon, it must be shown which polygon the point belongs to.

[image]

I tried to set up a condition using the "if" inside the "for" but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently merge GeoDataFrames if Polygon from one contains Point from second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211441/efficiently-merge-geodataframes-if-polygon-from-one-contains-point-from-second)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask